# C# mouse event for class object

Tags: c#, mouseevent

First - I'm a graphics designer - not a programmer :/

I'm trying create simple aplication (C# windows Form application) with option to add some objects (PictureBox) and allow user to drag those PicturesBoxes on form (change their positon after adding to form).

I can do it for one PictureBox, but can't add function to all dinamic created objects :/

I have something like that for standard Picturebox4

```
    public bool moveDetect = false;

    private void pictureBox4_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        moveDetect = true;
    }

    private void pictureBox4_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (moveDetect)
        {
            Point pozycja = new Point();
            this.Cursor = new Cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle);
            pozycja = this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
            pictureBox4.Location = pozycja;
        }
    }
```

Does anyone know any tutorial showing how to add function like above to my simple class "myPictureBox : Picturebox"

My class is:

```
class myPictureBox : PictureBox
{

    public bool moveDetect = false;

    // constructor
    public myPictureBox(int w, int h, string name)
    {
        this.Width = w;
        this.Height = h;
        this.Image = Image.FromFile("../../Resources/" + name + ".png");
        Debug.WriteLine("Created ...");
    }

}
```

Constructor works good and show "Created..." in output. Cant add function to all objects :/

Thanks and Regards ;)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your code works fine with the event handlers MouseUp and MouseDown when you are working with PictureBoxes that you create at design time using the designer.

You can add these same event handlers to controls that are created dynamically when you instantiate them:

```
MyPictureBox dynamicPicBox = new MyPictureBox(800, 600, "JustATest");
dynamicPicBox.MouseDown += pictureBox_MouseDown;
```

this adds an event handler that maps to the method pictureBox_MouseDown

```
private void pictureBox_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    moveDetect = true;
}
```

Since your custom class is derived from PictureBox, it should recognize this type of event handler.